# Sveltekit - 500 process is not defined or exports is not defined

Tags: node.js, svelte, grpc-node, dgraph, sveltekit

I'm trying to call a GRPC service (a dGraph api) from a Sveltekit (`SvelteKit v1.0.0-next.114`) application.

I am using a `writable` store from `svelte/store`, and am able to log to the console the response from calling the GRPC service.

However, we I import the store into my svelte component, using the following, I get the below error.

```
 <script>
    import {resume_store} from '../../stores/resume';
    console.log($resume_store);
 </script>
```

## Error

```
500

process is not defined

node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/logging.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:9012:28
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:7:44
node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/metadata.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:9057:21
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:7:44
node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-credentials.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:9231:22
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:7:44
node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/index.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:15325:30
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:7:44
node_modules/dgraph-js/lib/util.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:15483:16
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:7:44
node_modules/dgraph-js/lib/types.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:15595:18
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:7:44
node_modules/dgraph-js/lib/dgraph.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:17224:15
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:7:44
node_modules/dgraph-js/lib/index.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:17254:18
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:7:44
@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js.js?v=d2c49382:17261:25
```

## Alternative Dqraph client

I also tried using [dgraph-js-http](https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph-js-http) client.

The observations (see below) were the same - that being, for a brief moment the page looked as expected.

Firstly, I was getting an error that looked like it was the same as described on https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2579. However, I didnt save this, so cannot paste the exact error here.

I then tried

1. deleting the `node_modules`
2. running `npm install`
3. running `npm dev run`

Then, however the following error occurred.

## Error - Buffer2 is undefined

```
500

Buffer2 is undefined

node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js-http.js?v=e33d301e:554:9
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js-http.js?v=e33d301e:7:44
node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js-http.js?v=e33d301e:1126:19
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js-http.js?v=e33d301e:7:44
node_modules/jws/index.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js-http.js?v=e33d301e:1306:22
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js-http.js?v=e33d301e:7:44
node_modules/jsonwebtoken/decode.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js-http.js?v=e33d301e:1339:15
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js-http.js?v=e33d301e:7:44
node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js-http.js?v=e33d301e:3396:15
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js-http.js?v=e33d301e:7:44
node_modules/dgraph-js-http/lib/clientStub.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js-http.js?v=e33d301e:3598:15
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js-http.js?v=e33d301e:7:44
node_modules/dgraph-js-http/lib/index.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js-http.js?v=e33d301e:4587:18
__require@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js-http.js?v=e33d301e:7:44
@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dgraph-js-http.js?v=e33d301e:4595:30
```

Other attempts included:

- Adding `export const hydrate = false;` to the `.svelte` file, however this made no difference.
- Related to the above point, I tried adding `context="module"` to the `<script>` tag, as this is what is shown in the Sveltekit docs related to hydrate - see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#ssr-and-javascript-hydrate. However this resulted in an error of `Cannot reference store value inside <script context="module">`

## Observations

For a brief moment the web page of the Sveltekit application does display the result from the dgraph grpc service call - for maybe a second. Then the error message, above, is displayed.

Comment: The `@grpc/grpc-js` library is only intended to work in Node.js. When you are getting this error, are you running it in Node.js, or somewhere else?

Comment: Well, the call to the grpc service works, and momentarily displays, before being replaced with the error message. However, your comment is interesting - while it is using node, it maybe that all js is run entirely in the browser.

Comment: I asked because `process` in the error message might be referring to the global of that name that exists in Node. If it is, the most likely cause of the error is that the code is running in some other environment. It's hard to tell though, because I can't see how you would even get a call stack in `grpc-js` with those files in that order.

Comment: My guess is the error is occurring when sveltekit attempts to hydrate. https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#ssr-and-javascript-hydrate try turning it off and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your recommendation, and have updated the post accordingly.